# how to change R console widht in Rpy2

Tags: python, r

Simple, sometimes I want to add print statements in a function implemented in R but called through the rpy2 interface. E.g.

```
> f = ro.r("""function() {print(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10))}""")
> f()
   [,1]
    [,2]
   [,3]
   [,4]
    [,5]
   [,6]

 [1,]
 -0.4025149
  0.08482761
  0.5222286
 -0.6421664
  0.09643256
  0.4578836

 [2,]
  1.4367681
 -1.37630002
 -2.4442379
  2.4023002
  1.43871003
 -0.3336321

... and so on
```

This output is completely unreadable. I have tried changing the column width but it seems to be completely ignored, neither of the following is working:

```
function(x, y) {
    options(width=200, max.levels=NULL)
    print(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10))
}
```

or

```
function(x, y) {
    options(width=200, max.levels=100)
    print(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10), width=200, max.levels=100)
}
```

I have tried many combinations of settings with `width` and and `max.levels`, both in the `print` and `options` arguments, but no success.

I know and can convert R objects to python objects and print those. But this is really tedious. I plan to use this mostly for debugging purposes, so I need a quick one-liner that I can insert in the R code.

Side question: why does `print` even have the `width` argument, it seems to ignored even in a normal R console.

Comment: Your question is about R, not about Python. Do not spamtag.

Comment: Please, I have no intension to spamtag. This question is about python as well, rpy2 is a python interface to R. The problems I encounter only happen when using R through the python interface.

Comment: I believe there is something happening in the rpy2 (=python) package that messes up the `print`. I will place the tag back for now. Feel free to remove it again if you still believe this is spamtag. But if you do, whould you mind to elaborate on the reason?